# how to convert single quotes list with double quotes list

Tags: python, list

I have a predefined list with single quotes and I want double quotes in each element.

for example, this is my predefined list

```
l = ['A','b']
```

the output I needed as the list only

```
l = ["A","b"]
```

I am trying with json but it is giving list as a string but I want list.

```
import json
l = ['A','b']
output = json.dumps(l)
print(type(output))
```

Comment: Lists of strings don't have quotes in Python. They are *defined* with quotes, and you can edit our own source code to your liking. What do you mean? Why not use `lst = ["A","b"]`?

Comment: The type of the output is indeed string, this what json.dumps does

Comment: @DaniMesejo yes, but I want list element in double quotes, have you any idea

Comment: I'll reiterate, where do you want the quotes? It seems to me, that you can simply type out the definition that you want! Please clarify your intent in the question.

Comment: @Felix I have a predefined list where each elements in a single quotes but I want each item in a list with double-quotes. and the type should be "list"

Comment: See the answer below. I think you have misunderstood how lists work.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference in your case. Try to print `l`:

```
l_double = ["A","b"]

l_single = ['A','b']

print(l_double)

print(l_single)
```

returns

```
['A', 'b']
['A', 'b']
```

In case you really want double quotes around you list items, try something like this:

```
l = ['A','b']

l_real_double = [f'"{c}"' for c in l]

print(l_real_double)
```

which prints

```
['"A"', '"b"']
```

Comment: This might actually be what they meant. In that case I would also explain how to print double quotes.

Comment: you like mean my now added paragraph?

Comment: That's useful too. But what I meant was how to print lists with double quotes, not adding them to items. Like `print(str(lst).replace('\'', '"'))` or something.

Comment: @AlexanderRiedel but I want only double quotes

Comment: @AlexanderRiedel bro I want output like ["A","B","C","D"]

Comment: yeah then go for @Felix answer here in the comments

Answer (score 0):

```
L = ['A', 'B', 'C']
print('[', end='') #just to print the opening third bracket [
for i in range(len(L)): #the variable i will assume the values from 0 to length of L - 1 i.e. the indices of the elements
    print('"' + L[i] + '"', end='') #display a double quote and the string inside it
    if i < len(L)-1:
        print(',', end=' ') #if i is not the index of the last element then display a comma after it
print(']') #just to print the closing third bracket ]
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.